# Concatenating an array of nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I tried to use the code below to concatenate multiple nested elements, and for some reason, `undefined` is showing up in my results.

```
arr = [
  {
    very_positive: ["It is certain.", "It is decidedly so.", "Without a doubt.", "Yes - definitely.", "You may rely on it."]
  },
  {
    positive: ["As I see it, yes.", "Most likely.", "Outlook good.", "Yes.", "Signs point to yes."]
  },
  {
    negative: ["Reply hazy, try again.", " Ask again later.", "Better not tell you now.", "Cannot predict now.", "Concentrate and ask again."]
  },
  {
    very_negative: ["Don't count on it.", "My reply is no.", "My sources say no.", "Outlook not so good.", "Very doubtful."]
  }
];

let flatArrObj = arr.map(list => `${list.very_positive} ${list.positive} ${list.negative} ${list.very_nagative}`)
```

Comment: Please correct the code formatting.

Comment: Your array elements don't have all the properties you're referencing. There's no `positive` property in the first object, so you get `undefined`

Comment: What is the desired outcome? Is it a single object with 4 properties (very_positive, positive, ...) each with a value that is an array of strings?

Comment: use ```flatMap``` instead of ```map```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array.map() takes each element of the array and applies a function to it, for concatenation you could use reduce, or more simply

```js
arr = [{
    very_positive: ["It is certain.", "It is decidedly so.", "Without a doubt.", "Yes - definitely.", "You may rely on it."]
  },
  {
    positive: ["As I see it, yes.", "Most likely.", "Outlook good.", "Yes.", "Signs point to yes."]
  },
  {
    negative: ["Reply hazy, try again.", "Ask again later.", "Better not tell you now.", "Cannot predict now.", "Concentrate and ask again."]
  },
  {
    very_negative: ["Don't count on it.", "My reply is no.", "My sources say no.", "Outlook not so good.", "Very doubtful."]
  }
];

let flatObj = [...arr[0].very_positive, ...arr[1].positive,  ...arr[2].negative,  ...arr[3].very_negative]

console.log(flatObj);
```

given your data structure.

Comment: Thanks bro... Do you mind making sharing anexample using reduce?

Answer (score 0):

```js
arr = [{
    very_positive: ["It is certain.", "It is decidedly so.", "Without a doubt.", "Yes - definitely.", "You may rely on it."]
  },
  {
    positive: ["As I see it, yes.", "Most likely.", "Outlook good.", "Yes.", "Signs point to yes."]
  },
  {
    negative: ["Reply hazy, try again.", " Ask again later.", "Better not tell you now.", "Cannot predict now.", "Concentrate and ask again."]
  },
  {
    very_negative: ["Don't count on it.", "My reply is no.", "My sources say no.", "Outlook not so good.", "Very doubtful."]
  }
];
let result = [];
// INSERTING VALUE AT SPECIFIC INDEX
function insertAt(array, index, ...elementsArray) {
  array.splice(index, 0, ...elementsArray);
}
// INSERTING OBJECT VALUES 
const pushInResult = (obj) => {
  Object.values(obj).forEach(value => insertAt(result, 0, ...value));
}
// LOOPING THOUGH ARRAY
arr.forEach(obj => pushInResult(obj));
// PRINTING FINAL ARRAY RESULT
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon looking at this question for the first time, I was like "Concentrate and ask again" :/

Your data structure for the `arr` seems confusing, with each element being a map with **only 1 entry**. I suppose you would want to make *each element in the array* a key-value pair because that seems to be the intention here.

Thus, I would rewrite your data structure like this:

```js
let obj = {
    very_positive: ["It is certain.", "It is decidedly so.", "Without a doubt.", "Yes - definitely.", "You may rely on it."],
    positive: ["As I see it, yes.", "Most likely.", "Outlook good.", "Yes.", "Signs point to yes."],
    negative: ["Reply hazy, try again.", " Ask again later.", "Better not tell you now.", "Cannot predict now.", "Concentrate and ask again."],
    very_negative: ["Don't count on it.", "My reply is no.", "My sources say no.", "Outlook not so good.", "Very doubtful."]
}; // I am guessing that you're making an 8-ball, cool!
```

On this part, your question wasn't really clear. Do I concatenate each **category**'s responses, or do I combine **every single response** into one string?

You can use the `Array.prototype.join` method for joining the strings together. The `join` method "joins" the elements inside it, presumably `String`s (if not, that element will be coerced to a `String` somehow.) You can optionally pass inside the method a separator that is put between the elements.
[Array.prototype.join MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Example:

```js
let array = ["bread", "peanut", "butter"];
console.log(array.join()); // Should output breadpeanutbutter
console.log(array.join("-")); // Should output bread-peanut-butter
```

Since you need to apply this `join` method to *each and every* element in the array, you can and have used the method `Array.prototype.map`. [Array.prototype.map MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Example:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(arr.map(num => num * num)); // Should output Array 1, 4, 9, 16
```

Since all of the above methods only work with `Array`s, you can use either `Object.keys(obj)` to get all the keys of an object as an array, or `Object.values(obj)` to get the values instead to do things with it, which is what I do here. [Object.values MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Example:

```js
let obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
console.log(Object.values(obj)); // Should output Array [1, 2, 3]
console.log(Object.keys(obj)); // Should output Array ["a", "b", "c"]
```

#### Skip this code if "combining everything together" is your intention! Screw my 30 minutes of intensive writing!

Using everything above, your code can look like this:

```js
const eight_ball_responses = { // Snazzy name, I know
  very_positive: ["It is certain.", "It is decidedly so.", "Without a doubt.", "Yes - definitely.", "You may rely on it."],
  positive: ["As I see it, yes.", "Most likely.", "Outlook good.", "Yes.", "Signs point to yes."],
  negative: ["Reply hazy, try again.", " Ask again later.", "Better not tell you now.", "Cannot predict now.", "Concentrate and ask again."],
  very_negative: ["Don't count on it.", "My reply is no.", "My sources say no.", "Outlook not so good.", "Very doubtful."]
};

const flat_eight_ball_responses = Object
  .values(eight_ball_responses) // Get all the responses of the 8-ball
  .map(responses => responses.join(" ")); // Join each category's array of responses, which leaves an array of 4 strings for each category
  
console.log(flat_eight_ball_responses);
// For the question author: you might want to use flat_eight_ball_responses.join() instead, depending on your intention. The question wasn't really clear on this.
```

If you log the resulting object, it should look something like:

```
["It is certain. It is decidedly so. Without a doubt. Yes - definitely. You may rely on it.", "As I see it, yes. Most likely. Outlook good. Yes. Signs point to yes.", "Reply hazy, try again.  Ask again later. Better not tell you now. Cannot predict now. Concentrate and ask again.", "Don't count on it. My reply is no. My sources say no. Outlook not so good. Very doubtful."]
```

or even:

```
It is certain. It is decidedly so. Without a doubt. Yes - definitely. You may rely on it. As I see it, yes. Most likely. Outlook good. Yes. Signs point to yes. Reply hazy, try again. Ask again later. Better not tell you now. Cannot predict now. Concentrate and ask again. Don't count on it. My reply is no. My sources say no. Outlook not so good. Very doubtful.
```

Instead of a new array, you can probably also modify the object in place too, and preserve the category names.

```js
const eight_ball_responses = { // Snazzy name, I know
  very_positive: ["It is certain.", "It is decidedly so.", "Without a doubt.", "Yes - definitely.", "You may rely on it."],
  positive: ["As I see it, yes.", "Most likely.", "Outlook good.", "Yes.", "Signs point to yes."],
  negative: ["Reply hazy, try again.", " Ask again later.", "Better not tell you now.", "Cannot predict now.", "Concentrate and ask again."],
  very_negative: ["Don't count on it.", "My reply is no.", "My sources say no.", "Outlook not so good.", "Very doubtful."]
};

// Using Objects.entries give both the key and the value in one array/tuple
for (const [category, responses] of Object.entries(eight_ball_responses)) {
  eight_ball_responses[category] = responses.join(" ");
}

console.log(eight_ball_responses);
```

`very-positive`! (which means cheers, dear lord)